# HTML/CSS Make a Progress Bar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a progress bar as is shown [here](http://findmatthew.com/) in the about section however I am just lost.

I can make a bar and a box but neither look anywhere near as good as that and I cannot for the life of me get them to be beside each other with equal height. I just keep getting something along the lines of

[image]

What I am trying to achieve in case website goes down:
[image]

```css
.myskills {
  width: 45vw;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  margin: 1em;
}

.skillbarContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 2vh;
}

.skillName {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 5vw;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.meter {
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  /* Can be anything */
  position: relative;
  background: #555;
  padding: 3px;
}

.meter>span {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: hotpink;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="myskills">
  <div class="skillbarContainer">
    <div class="skillName">HTML</div>
    <div class="meter">
      <span style="width: 80%"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: html5 provides a [progress element](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/)

Comment: Please provide an image of your target in case that site goes down or removes its progress bar.

Comment: You can get idea from this https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_progressbar.asp

Comment: @JanithaRasanga w3fools shouldn't be the source for learning stuff related to programming

Comment: @HereticMonkey Done! Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, IMO you should use less `vh` and `vw`. Your font simply defines the height and the width of the text part. By removing them, you get something as you want as I understood (I also removed useless properties) :

```css
.myskills {
  width: 45vw;
  background: red;
  margin: 1em;
}

.skillbarContainer {
  display: flex;
}

.skillName {
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.meter {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  /* Can be anything */
  position: relative;
  background: #555;
  padding: 3px;
}

.meter>span {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: hotpink;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="myskills">
  <div class="skillbarContainer">
    <div class="skillName">HTML</div>
    <div class="meter">
      <span style="width: 80%"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, if it was my progress bar I'd use `flex` instead of `width` for `.meter`, I'd take a smaller font size and put padding to the text :

```css
.myskills {
  width: 45vw;
  background: red;
  margin: 1em;
}

.skillbarContainer {
  display: flex;
}

.skillName {
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.meter {
  float: left;
  flex: 1;
  /* Can be anything */
  position: relative;
  background: #555;
  padding: 3px;
}

.meter>span {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: hotpink;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="myskills">
  <div class="skillbarContainer">
    <div class="skillName">HTML</div>
    <div class="meter">
      <span style="width: 80%"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ItsOYo Your welcome. In the future, use the `vw` and `vh` ony if you *really* want the element to be a portion of the screen's size. Otherwise, it is more predictable to use width, heights and font size in pixels, and use `@media screen` to adapt to a screen size. Also, in a flexbox, use `flex-grow` (or `flex`) instead of using `%`.

Comment: Actually % is always preferred instead of px, at least in the responsive world. Flex, yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

This code below will give you the percentage sign on the right of the percentage bar. A lot of this is purely layering with hmtl/css.

Here are some links for layering and z-index:
[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_layers.htm#:~:text=The%20CSS%20layers%20refer%20to,element%20should%20come%20at%20bottom](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_layers.htm#:%7E:text=The%20CSS%20layers%20refer%20to,element%20should%20come%20at%20bottom).

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

```css
.myskills {
  width: 90%%;
  background: red;
  margin: 1em;
}

.skillbarContainer {
  display: flex;
}
.skillLevel{
  right: 0;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  position: absolute;
}
.skillName {
  background-color: rgb(77, 252, 208);
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.meter {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  /* Can be anything */
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(218, 217, 217);
  padding: 3px;
}

.meter>span {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(31, 134, 117);
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="myskills">
  <div class="skillbarContainer">
    
    <div class="skillName">HTML</div>
    <div class="meter">
      <span style="width: 80%"><span class="skillLevel">90%</span></span>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```